# Tracking php high cpu usage

Tags: php, codeigniter, optimization, cpu

I have a few codeigniter controllers executed through command line. They are big and complex scripts.

I've been experiencing high cpu loads on my server and tracked down the cause to those scripts.

Is there a way to know what part of the scripts is eating up the cpu?

The scripts are running on a ubuntu and php 5.3

Comment: I would recommend timing the execution time to your main functions and see which are the ones that take longer, as a beginning. Have you tried codeigniter's benchmark library?

Comment: The benchmark library can measure execution time and memory usage. I was looking for a more direct way to measure CPU usage. If the only solution turns out to be measuring execution time, I'll use the benchmark lib..

Comment: I use `htop` to see process's execution time/memory usage/cpu usage ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some like xhprof to profile your php scripts. [Profiling with xhprof](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/)

Comment: Looks interesting, it has a cpu load profiler. Will try it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in profiler

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

---

edit:

sorry, just saw someone mentioned this in the comments... Leaving for posterity.